# Handle feature on Drag and Drop, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, position

I'm creating a Drag and Drop plugin.
Right now i'm trying to create as many as features as possible. My current goal is to get my `handle` feature to work.

This is the code i'm using:

```
$(o.handle).mousedown(function (event) {
    down = true;
    if (o.activeClass === true) {
        $(oj).addClass(o.activeClass);
    }
    var dx = event.clientX - $(o.handle).position().left,
        dy = event.clientY - $(o.handle).position().top;
    $(o.handle).mousemove(function (event) {
        if (down == true) {
            if (o.dragClass === true) {
                $(oj).addClass(o.dragClass);
            }
            $(oj).css({
                cursor: 'move',
                left: event.clientX - dx,
                top: event.clientY - dy
            });
        }
    }); 
});
```

About the Code. `oj` is referring to `this`. `this` is the element that is being dragged by the handle.
`o.handle` is referring to the element of the handle. The `o` in `o.handle` is referring to:

`var o = $.extend(defaults, options);`

Problem: The First time I try to click on `o.handle`. The element jumps to: `top:0px;left:0px;`. Then it drags fine. But then once I drop it and then pick up the element and try to drag it again. It jumps to: `top:0px;left:1px;`. This happens over and over, non stop. I don't why though. You can see the problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MUZCR/24/show/). Do you see an error in my code?

**Thanks for any help**

Comment: Is there some reason you've chosen not to use or can't use the JQuery draggable() and droppable()? Just curious.

Comment: I don't see why people always say that. Im not creating a plugin for myself. Im trying to create a plugin for other people to try. And use. And just have fun with. A plugin that will have features that will beat any other plugin

Comment: Trying to create a better plugin qualifies, I think, as a good reason for not using what's already there. I suspect the reason others may wonder is that they (including me) are seriously time limited. My original comment was an attempt to find out if there was a reason I shouldn't use draggable/droppable.

Comment: You can if you want to. I dont care.